# Breaking up one array into multiple arrays in Postman

Tags: xcode, api, google-sheets, postman

Sorry to bother with such a lame question. I am pretty much very new to programming, and this is my first question in the stack overflow ever, so please don't be too hard on me.

I am trying to practice creating apps. My current app has to hold some stats, updated manually every day. Say I want to have something like this:

client  age height  weight  bloodpressure
Tim     45  170     75      140
Jim     33  183     80      120
Mike    36  180     83      130

And I am going to manually update the blood pressure column every day.

I understand that for this reason, I need an API. A somewhat reasonable solution for me would be to create a google spreadsheet and then to convert it to API thru sheet.best service. I then use the address in my swift code call on this data. Here’s the code that I’m using:

```
func getAllClients(){
AF.request("https://sheet.best/api/bla-bla-bla", headers: headers).responseJSON {response in
    let result = response.value
       if result != nil {
        let dataDictionary = result as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
        for clientData in dataDictionary {
            print(clientData)
```

However, here’s the problem. It returns back only one array in the debug section, which reads as follows:

```
[{"client":"Tim","age":"45","height":"170","weight":"75","bloodpressure":"140"},{"client":"Jim","age":"33","height":"183","weight":"80","bloodpressure":"120"},{"client":"Mike","age":"36","height":"180","weight":"83","bloodpressure":"130"}]
```

This is only one array []. What I need instead is three consecutive arrays:

```
["client":"Tim","age":"45","height":"170","weight":"75","bloodpressure":"140"]
["client":"Jim","age":"33","height":"183","weight":"80","bloodpressure":"120"]
["client":"Mike","age":"36","height":"180","weight":"83","bloodpressure":"130"]
```

so I could further create local variables: client, age, height, weight, bloodpressure and then create a client data table, sortable by parameters of my choosing.

Question: How do I use Postman to break down one array into three arrays as I showed above? Or alternatively, how could I adjust the google spreadsheet so it automatically gives me three arrays (cause I haven’t yet built confidence in coding). Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You have one array of dictionaries. That’s perfect. Create a custom struct and decode the JSON to an array of instances of that struct. Your approach with multiple arrays is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being returned is a list of objects. There is no need of converting that into arrays. you can map inside that one array and access the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But still, if I want to have multiple arrays, what do I do?